# Error: CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

I'm new to coding, I have tried to create a login form with a SQL Server database but for some reason, it doesn't register it.

I took the data source directly from my SQL Server name. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Opgave.Models;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Opgave.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader dr;

        // GET: User
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }
        
        void connectionString()
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "data source=LAPTOP-UMVUL6BV\SQLEXPRESS; database=SkoleNavn; integrated security=SSPI;";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Verify(UserLogin2 Acc)
        {
            connectionString();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "select * from UserLogin where Email='"+Acc.email+"' and Password='"+Acc.password+"'";

            dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                con.Close();
                return View("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                con.Close();
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***. also: ***never*** store passwords as plain text! hash them!. and to get to your question: try replacing "\" with "\\" in your connection string. and maybe [read up on strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: The error message is complaining about the `\S` characters in `data source=LAPTOP-UMVUL6BV\SQLEXPRESS`. Try either a Verbatim String Literal which starts with a `@` character, e.g. `@"Single\Backslashes\Are\Ok\Here"` or escape the backslash with another one, e.g. `"This\\Needs\\Doubled\\Backslashes"`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, C# allows you to write combinations of characters into strings and they will be interpreted as other characters when the compiler is processing the code:

```
string containsNewline = "abc\ndef";
string containsTab     = "abc\tdef";
```

Both these strings will end up 7 characters long in the actual compiled program; one contains a newline, the other a tab. The `\n` and `\t` are referred to as escape sequences - a slash starts it and the next character dictates what the result will be.

You put a string of:

```
con.ConnectionString = "data source=LAPTOP-UMVUL6BV\SQLE
                                                   ^^
```

The compiler error is telling you "I don't know of any character that is represented by the escape sequence `backslash-S`"

Because it's not an escape sequence you want to use at all, but a literal slash followed by a literal S, you either have to turn off escaping by putting an @ before the string `"` delimiter:

```
con.ConnectionString = @"data source=LAPTOP-UMVUL6BV\SQLE
```

Or you leave the escaping mechanism active, but use `\\` which means "the first slash starts escape interpretation and the next character (also a slash) means "put a literal `\` character into the string. Thus two `\\` become one `\` after the escaping is processed

```
con.ConnectionString = "data source=LAPTOP-UMVUL6BV\\SQLE
```